# ¿Como insertar datos en una base de datos MySQL desde python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

tengo esta tabla:

```
id_evento          uid  
Primaria-AN-INT10  varchar30
```

y quiero insertarle datos desde sus respectivas variables

```
insertar="INSERT INTO eventos (id_evento,uid VALUES (%s,%s)"
datos=(???,uid)
cursor1.execute(insertar,datos)
```

sabiendo que la conexion de labase de dato esta bien porque coonsult datoos de ellas y con el dato que id_evento es clave primaria y autonumerica si la omito en el query me da error por falta de argumentos

Answer (score 0):

Asi lo resolvi:

```
self.valornull=0  #el valor es autonumerico asi que le paso o como NULL
insertar="INSERT INTO `eventos` (`id_evento`, `uid`) VALUES (%s,%s);"
datos=(self.valornull, card_id)
cursor1.execute(insertar,datos)
```